# Problem with Categories in Wordpress!

Tags: wordpress, post

**My Original question was this:**

> I have a wordpress installation where
>   the Home page is set to display post
>   from a specific category. To achieve
>   this, I created a template "home.php"
>   and put the following code:
>
> ```
> query_posts( 'cat=4&order=desc' );
> ```
>
> When I visit the site's home page, it
>   display posts from the category but
>   the Navigation does not work? I have
>   permalink structure set
>   "/%category%/%postname%/"
>
> Please let me know if I am doing
>   something wrong.

**Update:**
Now, I have solved this using this code:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    $args = array (
        'cat' => 4,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'desc',
        'posts_per_page' => '10'
        );
    query_posts($args . '&paged=' . $paged);
```

Now the problem is that first time, it displays everything fine but if you visit any other archive page, it start displaying posts from other categories. For example, the above code displays posts from Cat=>3 as well. And on page, where I want to display posts from Category = 3, it display posts from category 4 as well.

Please help...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "Navigation"? What code are you using for the navigation? Are you limiting the amount of posts?
If you have problems with the pagination. You can use this:

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
        query_posts("cat=4&order=desc&paged=$paged"); ?>
```

Please, Clarify your problems to help you.

Comment: WillxD, thank you so much. I was not including $paged variable in the query. So each time page loads, it display first 10 posts. But the code you sent needs some medification: get_query_var('paged') does not work however get_query_var('page') does work. Anyway, Thank you so much...